# Django - images not displayed

Tags: django, image

I work on a Django project and I want to display some images to templates, but although I can upload them, I can not display them.

```
class Sindiasmoi(models.Model):
    sindid = models.AutoField(db_column='sindID', primary_key=True, db_index=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    descr = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    shortdescr = models.CharField(db_column='shortDescr', max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
    photo = models.ImageField(db_column='photo',upload_to='sindiasmoi',default='elections.jpg',null=True, blank=True)
    eidos = models.IntegerField(default=1)

def __str__(self):
    return self.descr

class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = 'SINDIASMOI'
```

My view is:

```
def pososta_telika(request, eklid):
    # φιλτράρισμα επιλεγμένης εκλ. αναμέτρησης
    selected_ekloges = Eklogestbl.objects.get(eklid=eklid)
    # επιλογή όλων των εκλ. αναμετρήσεων με visible=1 και κάνω φθίνουσα ταξινόμηση  αν δεν δοθεί παράμετρος
    all_ekloges = Eklogestbl.objects.filter(visible=1).order_by('-eklid')
    #ανάκτηση εγγραφών επιλεγμένης εκλ. αναμέτρησης από το σχετικό database view
    all_pososta = EklSumpsifodeltiasindVw.objects.filter(eklid=eklid).order_by('-posostosindiasmou')

    context = {'all_pososta':all_pososta, 'all_ekloges':all_ekloges, 'selected_ekloges':selected_ekloges.eklid}

    return render(request, 'Elections/pososta_telika.html',context)
```

My template code has code below:

```
{% for p in all_pososta %}

    <img src="{{ p.sindid.photo}}" alt="image"/>
{% endfor %}
```

Als I added row below in my settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And finally my urls.py has code below:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'', include('Elections.urls')),
    path('admin_tools/', include('admin_tools.urls')),
]


urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns = [
        path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),

        # For django versions before 2.0:
        # url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),

    ] + urlpatterns
```

I have tried to replace {{ p.sindid.photo}} with {{ p.sindid.photo.url}}, but that throws an error like "'bytes' object has no attribute 'url'"

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: show this model EklSumpsifodeltiasindVw

Comment: Look at the HTML source in your browser to see how your img src looks like. Normally you should use `{% get_media_url %}{{p.sindid.photo.url}}` in your template to get the correct path. That is, if p.sindid.photo is correct to reference the image but you don’t show the model for p so I can’t tell.

Answer (score 0):

Also, below is my model EklSumpsifodeltiasindVw if helps anyone:

```
class EklSumpsifodeltiasindVw(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    eklid = models.ForeignKey(Eklogestbl, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='eklID', db_index=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sindid = models.ForeignKey(Sindiasmoi, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='sindID', db_index=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sindiasmos = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    shortdescr = models.CharField(db_column='shortDescr', max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
    photo=models.ImageField(db_column='photo',null=True)
    sumvotes = models.DecimalField(db_column='sumVotes', max_digits=32, decimal_places=0, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sinola = models.DecimalField(max_digits=32, decimal_places=0, blank=True, null=True)
    katametrimena = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    plithoskentrwn = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='plithosKentrwn')  # Field name made lowercase.
    posostosindiasmou = models.DecimalField(db_column='posostoSindiasmou', max_digits=38, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    posostokatametrimenwnkentrwn = models.DecimalField(db_column='posostoKatametrimenwnKentrwn', max_digits=26, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sumvotesb = models.DecimalField(db_column='sumVotesB', max_digits=32, decimal_places=0, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sinolab = models.DecimalField(db_column='sinolaB', max_digits=32, decimal_places=0, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    posostosindiasmoub = models.DecimalField(db_column='posostoSindiasmouB', max_digits=38, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    katametrimenab = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='katametrimenaB', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    posostokatametrimenwnkentrwnb = models.DecimalField(db_column='posostoKatametrimenwnKentrwnB', max_digits=26, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sumvotesk = models.DecimalField(db_column='sumVotesK', max_digits=32, decimal_places=0, blank=True,
                                    null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sinolak = models.DecimalField(db_column='sinolaK', max_digits=32, decimal_places=0, blank=True,
                                  null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    posostosindiasmouk = models.DecimalField(db_column='posostoSindiasmouK', max_digits=38, decimal_places=2,
                                             blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    katametrimenak = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='katametrimenaK', blank=True,
                                            null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    posostokatametrimenwnkentrwnk = models.DecimalField(db_column='posostoKatametrimenwnKentrwnK', max_digits=26,
                                                        decimal_places=2, blank=True,
                                                        null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

This is a mysql database view.

Also, my HTML code about images, as shown in browser is:

```
<img src="b&#39;DSC00176.JPG&#39;" alt="image"/>


                <img src="b&#39;sindiasmoi/DSC00239_7GGlF7a.JPG&#39;" alt="image"/>


                <img src="b&#39;DSC00165.JPG&#39;" alt="image"/>


                <img src="b&#39;wwf_earth_hour_2018.jpg&#39;" alt="image"/>


                <img src="b&#39;sindiasmoi/DSC00240.JPG&#39;" alt="image"/>


                <img src="b&#39;sindiasmoi/DSLSPEED07102017_cfQWRL6.PNG&#39;" alt="image"/>
```

I think something is not ok with path.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem solved!

The problem was this line:
photo=models.ImageField(db_column='photo',null=True)

I should not include "db_column='photo'". When I removed this parameter, everything worked fine.